# Is there a way to evaluate this infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{3n^2+2}$

In my calculus 2 class, we were testing the convergence of different series by using the direct comparison test and confirmed that this one converges, but I tried to evaluate it afterward to no avail. I factored the denominator then used partial fraction decomposition to separate the roots, but I'm not sure that got me any closer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a way to evaluate the sum, but not, so far as I know, with the techniques of Calculus 2.  If you look at equation $18$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cotangent.html), you'll see that you can do it in terms of the cotangent function, but you need to set $z=i\sqrt{\frac23}.$  That is, you need the calculus of functions of a complex variable, and you're quite a ways from that yet.  There are lots of convergent sums that can't be evaluated in closed from, so it's useful to learn how to approximate them.  (Of course, in this case, you can just type the sum into WolframAlpha.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a known rational function power series [(see Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Rational_functions) which we can manipulate your summation into:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + a^2} = \frac{1 + a \pi \coth(a \pi)}{2a^2}$$

From your power series, we will add and subtract an $n=0$ term first, pulling the added one into the summation:

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3n^2 + 2} = - \frac 1 2 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3n^2 + 2}$$

Next, we pull out a factor of $1/3$ from the summation:

$$S = - \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + 2/3}$$

Apply the initial formula we referenced with $a=\sqrt{2/3}$; with some simplifying,

$$S =  \frac{-1 + \pi \sqrt{2/3} \cdot \coth( \pi \sqrt{2/3})}{4} \approx 0.398906832$$

Of course, justifying the original power series is probably well beyond Calculus II levels, as noted in the comments of your question, but I'm not sure how else this series might be evaluated. Verifying the convergence isn't troublesome as I imagine you noticed - finding the actual value, however, can be quite the task for many infinite sums of rational functions.

Of course, there might be other methods, who knows. I wouldn't get my hopes up on the matter though.

Answer (score 1):

The series can be estimated directly by a partial sum

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{a-1} \frac {1}{3n^2+2}$$

and estimating the error by integral test

$$\int_a^\infty \frac {1}{3x^2+2}dx\le \sum_{n=a}^{\infty} \frac {1}{3n^2+2}\le f(a)+\int_a^\infty \frac {1}{3x^2+2}dx$$

For example for $a=10$ we obtain

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{9} \frac {1}{3n^2+2}\approx 0.364$$

$$0.0333 \approx\int_{10}^\infty \frac {1}{3x^2+2}dx\le \sum_{n=10}^{\infty} \frac {1}{3n^2+2}\le f(a)+\int_{10}^\infty \frac {1}{3x^2+2}dx\approx 0.0363$$

therefore

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{3n^2+2}\in [0.3973,0.4003]$$

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the sum is approximately $0.3973 - 0.4003$ which is negative? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Math1000 No! I mean it is between those values! Which symbol can I use?

Comment: I would just say it is in the interval $(0.3973, 0.4003)$, I suppose.

Comment: @Math1000 Ah ok, I'll use that notation then.